# Passing Interface props in functional component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

Error:

[image]

Actually, I can solve this error if I add a question mark on my interface. However, I expected it should work without a question mark. Am I missing something or is it right to add a question mark?

This is 'Main.tsx'

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ICamp {
  id: number;
  type: 'popular' | 'specialDiscount';
  dateStart: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  campName: string;
  //인가 부트 캠프
  status?: '모집전' | '모집중' | '모집완료';
  //특가 할인 캠프
  category?: string;
  //커뮤니티
  tag?: '조회수 TOP' | '취업 고민';
}

// export default function Main(props: ICamp) {
//   return <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>This is main</div>;
// }

export const Main: React.FC<ICamp> = ICamp => {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>This is main</div>;
};
```

This is Router.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './components/Nav/Nav';
import { Main } from './main/Main';
import Detail from './detail/Detail';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/main" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default Router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a functional component and tell TypeScript, that you want to pass mandatory props data to this component. If you don't need to pass any props to your component, you can mark them as "optional" by adding a question mark.

By reading your code for the router, I see you don't have passed in that mandatory props data and thus, TypeScript will throw an error.

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate your help! I got your point!
Then, If I receive data from the back-end, I can receive and use it in Main.tsx, right? If I use with question mark

Comment: If you receive any data from the back-end you can pass that data to your Main.tsx component. But if you are unsure if some data parts don't exist, you can mark them as optional with a question mark. I highly recommend you reading about how React handles functional components with states, props and hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to pass at least the following props to the component:

```
id: number;
type: 'popular' | 'specialDiscount';
dateStart: string;
thumbnail: string;
campName: string;
```

like that:

```
element={<Main id={1} ... />} />
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your comment!
Oh, I see. So, If I receive data from the back-end, do I have to pass the props in Router.js?

Comment: When I do a code in Javascript, I receive the data in Main.js, not a Router.js and it sounds makes sense... I think.. Receiving a data in Main.tsx rather than Router.tsx